# define a string as POST request using AJAX in the same page onclick

Tags: php, ajax

for the PHP is just simple check:

All in the same page named **

### page.php

```
if(isset($_POST['XYZ']){
    echo "WORKING";
}
```

then for my HTML:

```
<h1 id='XYZ'>CLICK ME</h1>
```

now at the same page i'm trying to do the AJAX POST request like this

```
$('#XYZ').click(function(){
    var XYZ = 'XYZ';
    $.post('page.php',{
        XYZ: XYZ
    })
})
```

and the request didn't work, How do i just pass the `$_POST` data? I removed `success` function since i didn't think it is useful in this case.

What i want is when i click on the `<h1>` the `echo` appears.

Comment: I advise you to dive into jquery manual. You will find that `$('XYZ')` selects __nothing__ and `$.post` has different order of arguments.

Comment: you'll need the `success` callback to receive the returning "Working"!

Comment: @Jeff How to do that exactly? I just want to make the `$_POST['XYZ']` available? I know it is a newbie question, But all i know is how to send the data to a div in `.html`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var my_string = 'xyz';
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: { "action":my_string},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        if(response['state'] == 'ok'){
            console.log("ok");
        }
    }
});
```

**ajax.php**

```
<?php echo $_POST['action']; ?>
```

Comment: didn't work, same problem as before, nothing happens.

Comment: @CaliburVictorious add this code `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to php file and run it like this http://example.com/ajax.php maybe your php code has some errors

Comment: Still nothing happens, Just to be sure, the `ajax.php` is the same page that has the `ajax` code, right? Because i'm trying to make the page show the `echo` after i click on the `h1` automatically instead of redirecting to another page and showing the values.

Comment: your jquery selector is also wrong. read the first comment of u_mulder!

Comment: @Jeff just wrote it wrong in the question, The selector, And i don't get the problem of `$.post`

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
 <script>
   var my_string = 'xyz';
   $.ajax({
       method: 'POST',
        url: './giveposts',
          dataType: "text",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          data:my_string,
   success: function(data) {
      {
        $("#test").html(data);
       }
    }
});
 </head>
  </script>
   <body>
  <div id="test>
     /*echo 
  </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: should be `method: 'POST'` - or he needs to change the php.

Comment: also the selector is false, as @u_mulder pointed out. (and a js without script-tags?)

Comment: I Edit My answer Check Now

Comment: But like that i think i call the data into a `div`, But i just want to assign the variable in the same page to get the `if(isset($_POST['XYZ'])){}` working without reloading the page.

Comment: I send your request as text  and when data sent div with test id loaded